# Добавление нового объекта в массив объекта

Tags: javascript

У меня есть некий объект:

```
myObj = {
    "user": "John",
    "kanz": []
}
```

Каким образом можно в массив `kanz` положить несколько других объектов, например таких:

```
 {
    "number": "1",
    "code": "123",
 }
```

Чтобы в итоге было такое:

```
 myObj = {
    "user": "John",
    "kanz": [
         {
           "number": "1",
           "code": "123",
         },
         {
           "number": "2",
           "code": "1234",
         }//итд
    ]
}
```

Как это сделать на JavaScript?

Comment: каким боком тут jquery?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jQuery в данном случае вам не нужен.
Достаточно нативного JavaScript:

```
let new_obj = {
  "number": "1",
  "code": "123"
};

myObj.kanz.push(new_obj);
```

Рекомендую: [Современный учебник Javascript](https://learn.javascript.ru/) ☺

Answer (score 3):

Добавляются элементы так же, как и в любой другой массив, с помощью метода [`push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)

```
myObj.kanz.push({
    "number": "1",
    "code": "123",
});
```